# Как убрать приведение типа из конструкции фреймворка Spring `applicationContext.getBean`?

Tags: java, spring

Типичная для Spring строка кода:

```java
IFilesManager filesManager = (dev.example.FilesManager.FilesManager) applicationContext.getBean("FilesManager");
```

, где `IFilesManager` - интерфейс или абстрактный класс.

Вроде бы все эти финты с бинами придуманы для того, чтобы убрать жесткую связь приложения с конкретными реализациями, а в коде ссылаться только на абстракции. Но ведь для того, чтобы этот код скомпилировался, нам нужно импортировать явно `FilesManager`. Получается, мы жестко ссылаемся на этот класс - не вижу, какое преимущество перед тем, что если бы мы написали по-дедовски:

```java
IFilesManager filesManager = new FilesManager();
```

Если же мы перепишем так:

```java
IFilesManager filesManager = applicationContext.getBean("FilesManager");
```

то, поскольку `applicationContext.getBean()` возвращает Object, код не скомпилируется.

Можно ли переписать этот код так, чтобы ссылаться исключительно на абстракцию `IFilesManager`, а реализацию `FilesManager` не импортировать?

Кстати, по слухам, холивар между приверженцами Spring-контекста в xml-файлах и приверженцев аннотаций `@Bean` кончился в пользу последних. Не умею пока использовать `@Bean`-аннотации, но ответы с `@Bean`-аннотацией приветствуются.

Спасибо, что прочитали вопрос.

Comment: Может я не понял вопрос, но у метода getBean бывает и 2 аргумента, насколько я помню : applicationContext.getBean("FilesManager", IFilesManager.class);

Comment: @Дмитрий, прошу прощения за непонятный вопрос. Сейчас буду редактировать. `IFilesManager` - это интерфейс, правда уже отрефакторил и сменил интерфейс на абстрактный класс. `IFilesManager.class` будет работать?

Comment: В крайнем случае вы можете просто привести к интерфейсу, а не к классу: `(IFilesManager) applicationContext.getBean("FilesManager");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать таким образом:

IFilesManager filesManager = applicationContext.getBean(IFilesManager.class);

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Работает.

Answer (score 1):

> Но ведь для того, чтобы этот код скомпилировался, нам нужно
>   импортировать явно FilesManager. Получается, мы жестко ссылаемся на
>   этот класс - не вижу, какое преимущество перед тем, что если бы мы
>   написали по-дедовски

Согласно документации Spring использование `applicationContext` где-либо кроме конфигурационных классов спринга - уже нарушение концепции инверсии контроля.

Лучший вариант - собирать бины в `*Configuration` классах, а там как раз и надо писать конкретные реализации:

```java
IFilesManager filesManager = new FilesManager();
```

Это и называется "инверсией контроля", так как объекты, которые используют `IFilesManager`, не занимаются получением экземпляров этого интерфейса, а этим занимается какая-то третья система/фреймворк/менеджер зависимостей.

Короче, ваши классы в Spring-приложении не должны знать о существовании Spring вообще, а вот он должен знать о них всё.

Лучший способ ответить на вопрос "А правильно ли я делаю" - сначала ответить на вопрос "Сможет ли мой код работать без спринга вообще, ну, например, с другим Dependency Injection фреймворком.

Прошу прощения, что ответ не совсем по теме, но для данного обсуждения следовало это упомянуть

Comment: Вы сказали очень ценные вещи, пускай не по теме, но очень важные. Спасибо вам большое за то, что потратили время на чтение вопроса и написание ответа!

Comment: Посмотрел пример на [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm) - там тоже `ApplicationContext` в `main`-методе создают. Не могли бы Вы дать ссылку с примером того, о чём Вы говорили? (о сборке бинов в `*Configuration`-классах)

Comment: Дело в том, что `main` метод это как раз часть кода, работающая с фреймворком, и он работает с контекстом напрямую (загрузить контекст, подключить классы конфигурации, в которых собираются бины, запустить старт всего приложения). "Собираются" объекты в том примере как раз в Configuration, а `main` их уже берёт из контекста готовенькие. Но обычно никто напрямую не вызывает `getBean`, а пользуется Dependency Injection аннотациями (`@Autowire`, например).

Comment: Понял. Тот самый лучший вариант, о котором Вы говорили - `ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Confing.class);` ?

Comment: Ну это правильный варивант. Про "лучший" не хочу отвечать "да" или "нет", потому что "лучшего" варианта нет. Главное не забывать то простое правило про "классы с логикой не должны знать ничего о фреймворке", остальное уже на ваше усмотрение

Comment: Понял, благодарю Вас за ответ и коментарии!