# Как обеспечить доступ к бинам для классов, не являющихся точкой входа в приложение (и бинами)?

Tags: java, spring, context, bean

Из ответов на вопрос [Как убрать приведение типа из конструкции фреймворка Spring `applicationContext.getBean`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117476/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-spring-applicationcontext/1117488?noredirect=1#comment1929969_1117488) я узнал, что для соблюдения инверсии контроля использовать `applicationContext` можно только в конфигурационных классах Spring, а также в точке входа, например:

```
public class EntryPoint {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationContext.class);
        FilesManager filesManager = applicationContext.getBean(FilesManager.class);
        PeopleGateway peopleGateway = applicationContext.getBean(PeopleGateway.class);

        filesManager.initializeUserFiles();
        GUI_Service.startGUI();
    }
}
```

Каким же образом принято обеспечивать доступ к бинам из всех остальных классов? Например, в данном приложении `GUI_Service` будет вызывать у `peopleGateway` разные методы - `getAllPeolple`, `getPersonByID` и так далее. К контексту `GUI_Service` обращаться вроде как не должен. А в точке входа `peopleGateway` пока что и вовсе не нужен.

Обычный способ - передать `peopleGateway` либо через конструктор `GUI_Service`, либо через какой-нибудь инициализирующий метод. Что даёт Spring?

`GUI_Service` на данный момент пока не является бином.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Спринге связать бины можно различными способами:

1) Связывание над сеттерами аннотацией `@Autowired` над ней.

2) Через поле и аннотацию, которая подтянет бин в классе `AppConfig`. Данный метод обозначен аннотацией `@Bean`, что автоматически подтягивает аргументы в метод.

3) Так же возможно конструировать через связывание по `@Autowired` с помощью конструктора. Необоходимо пометить все классы, которые являются бинами аннотацией `@Component`.Чтобы Спринг видел все бины, в классе `AppConfig` была добавлена аннотация `@ComponentScan`.

Ниже я представил пример 3-х различных вариантов связывания бинов. В практическом примере можно ознакомиться более детально.

https://github.com/ilya-yarets/2.1.4.spring-types-of-wiring

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ и пример! Подскажите пожалуйста, а если нужно передать контекст в классы не являющиеся бинами, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Для доступа к бинам используется аннотация @Autowired. Её можно вешать на поле или геттер.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Пробовал - если класс не является бином, то ApplicationContext - null. С бинами пока не пробовал.

Comment: @Боков Глеб , конечно объект должен быть бином. А именно отмечен, как Component / Service / Repository или собственно Bean