# JavaFX приложение падает при попытке сделать контроллер бином

Tags: java, spring, javafx

Из ответов на вопрос [Как обеспечить доступ к бинам для классов, не являющихся точкой входа в приложение (и бинами)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1119491/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd/1120525#1120525) я так и не узнал, как же обеспечить доступ к бинам для тех классов, которые сами бинами не являются. Пришлось делать делать JavaFX-контроллер бином:

```java
@Component
public class PersonOverviewController {

  private final PeopleGateway peopleGateway;

  // ...

  @Autowired
  public PersonOverviewController(PeopleGateway peopleGateway) {
    this.peopleGateway = peopleGateway;
  }

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {

    System.out.println("===");
    System.out.println(peopleGateway);
    // Если инъекция произведена успешно, то это не должен быть null    
  }

  // ...
}
```

Привело это к тому, что приложение стало падать по непонятной мне причине. Из сообщений об ошибке ясно, что JavaFX то ли потерял контроллер, то ли не может им манипулировать:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: dev.example.Controllers.PersonOverviewController
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:598)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:936)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: dev.example.Controllers.PersonOverviewController.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3427)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:585)
    ... 19 more
```

Конфигурация приложения:

```java
@Configuration
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

  @Bean
  public FilesManager filesManager() {
    return new RegularFilesManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public PeopleGateway peopleGateway() { return new PeopleGatewayWithMockData(); }

  @Bean
  public PersonOverviewController personOverviewController() {
    return new PersonOverviewController(this.peopleGateway());
  }
}
```

Полный код приложения доступен на [Bit-bucket-репозитории](https://bitbucket.org/TokugawaYD/javafx-spring-training/src/Error1/).
Также прилагаю ссылку на [код приложения в рабочем состоянии](https://bitbucket.org/TokugawaYD/javafx-spring-training/src/master/).

Comment: JavaFX создает сам объекты контроллеров через рефлексию. А спринг создаст вам один объект этого бина (Если не изменен scope бина), но JavaFX знать не знает об этом. Нужно писать некий мост между JavaFX и спрингом, что бы FX обращался к приснгу за объектом контроллера и т.д. Ибо даже если `scope` у бина будет `prototype` созданием объектов все равно будет заниматься спринг.

Comment: @Tsyklop, благодарю Вас за комментарий. Есть ли у Вас какие-нибудь ссылки по этому поводу?

Comment: скажите, а зачем вам потребовалось совмещать JavaFX и Spring? мне просто интересно, т.к. эти технологии из разных миров.JavaFX для создания десктопа, что само по себе попахивает извращением для Java. Spring - для разработки серверной части. это разные направления, потому как для сервера, к примеру, абсолютно неважно, как долго он будет стартовать, что не скажешь про десктоп. разные миры и разные подходы. так зачем их объединять?

Comment: @Дмитрий, может и незачем было совмещать, потому если есть что-то более подходящее, порекомедуйте пожалуйста. Меня интересует создание нативных приложений для всех популярных устройств (компьютеры, планшеты, смартфоны) и всех популярных OS (iOS, Android, Windows, Linux, MacOS), при этом код должен быть один на все устройства и ОС. JavaFX удовлетворяет этому требованию. Spring пока нужен только для инъекции зависимости, но со временем мне понадобятся плагины для чтения и записи в файл и для работы с БД (в том числе ORM). Хотя я и люблю изобретать велосипеды, мне сейчас уже есть, что изобретать.

Comment: На счет iOS, Android и JavaFX не все так радужно, особенно если использовать Spring, завязанный на рефлексию. Я немного эксперементировал со сборкой нативного приложения c GraalVM хотя бы под Linux (стек SpringBoot + JavaFX), но безуспешно.

Comment: @RuslanP., так, интересно, и какие же именно проблемы возникают? Я многого не знаю, и если просто смотреть с позиции моих текущих знаний, то JVM на разных устройствах должно быть всё равно, какие фреймворки использованы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FXMLLoader вроде как не умеет в constructor Injection, и контроллер создать не сможет, да и в данном случае не должен. Для использования "внешнего" DI предусмотрен специальный механизм c ControllerFactory:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();    
loader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);
```

ControllerFactory имеет тип `Callback<Class<?>, Object>`, в данном случае ссылка на метод, `applicationContext::getBean` где applicationContext - это спринговый  `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!